# Display CMS in Lightning web Component

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforce-cms, spring21

There is [this new feature](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_experiences_use_cms_in_custom_lwc.htm&type=5&release=230) to display CMS in Lightning web component but I didn't find any articles that show how to use it. Is it possible to display cms whit type different of image, like news for exemple?

When I try like this with contentkey of new cms nothing is displayed

```
<img data-contentkey='MCX3R5********JEUFCQSZYUSXXI'>  </img>
<div data-contentkey='MCX3R5********EUFCQSZYUSXXI'>  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this sample app - [AZ Insurance](https://github.com/trailheadapps/az-insurance). It has a lot of LWC components that use CMS. For example - [cmsNewsCardWithButton](https://github.com/trailheadapps/az-insurance/tree/main/force-app/main/default/lwc/cmsNewsCardWithButton). The app is open-source, so you can copy-paste/re-use these components/code.

These components use Apex to retrieve the content based on the `contentId` that is passed using the Experience Builder.

Comment: great thanks for the help, from what I see in this code there is no use of the new feature but I will use this code.